# Click function on element returned from the jquery load func

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I need to know how to call the click jquery function on an element returned by the load func (again jquery). I cant get the elements by class name and what I was thinking about is that they are not existing in the DOM when I try to get them.

here is my main page:

```
        <div id="content">
            <div id="main"></div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
```

I am loading additional html content inside the #main with the load() jquery function and it works just fine. So inside my #main I get a content like this:

```
<div id="home_container">
<div id="left_column" class="home_columns">
    <img src="images/code.jpg" alt="code" class="pics home_pics" />
    <p class="home_text">Code snippets</p>
</div>
<div id="center_column" class="home_columns">
    <img src="images/me_home.jpg" alt="me" class="pics home_pics" />
    <p class="home_text">About</p>
</div>
<div id="right_column" class="home_columns">
    <img src="images/contacts.jpg" alt="code" class="pics home_pics" />
    <p class="home_text">Contacts</p>
</div>
```

Then I am calling a jquery function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
"use strict";
$('div.home_columns').click(function () {
    console.log("clicked!");
});
});
```

But there is no "clicked!" log in the browsers console. What is the problem here? I think that when I am trying to bind the func to the div it is not inizialized? Am I right and if yes - how can I overcome this?

Thank you
Nikola

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i would just use [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for this:

```
$('#main').on('click', 'div.home_columns', function () {
    console.log("clicked!");
});
```

Comment: Thank you mate! That is just what I needed!